# Java: Efficient means of using mutually exclusive RegExs (15) for 2.5M Strings?

Tags: java, regex

My dilemma is as follows: I'm attempting to match Strings in an external file to *mutually-exclusive regular expressions* (i.e a String **cannot** match multiple RegExs

What algorithm would you suggest that would allow for me to match a given String to a RegEx that is guaranteed to not intersect with the other use-cases?

The program is syntactically valid, however there is overlapping as it stands. There are 2.5m lines in the file.

I was considering tokenizing each row in the file, then having flags for each condition (so, if 'x' contains [A-Z]+ set UPPERCASE flag)

> - Regular expressions must check for the presence of:
>
>   - *Punctuation*
>   - *Upper-case letters*
>   - *Lower-case letters*
>   - *Integers*

---

Possible use-cases where:

```
U = Upper-case letter L = Lower-case letter P = Punctuation N = Number

---- null
U--- [A-Z]+
UL-- [A-Za-z]+
U-N- [A-Z0-9]+
ULN- [A-Za-z0-9]+
ULNP [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z0-9]+
-L-- [a-z]+
-LN- [a-z0-9]+
--N- [0-9]
---P [\\p{Punct}\\s]+
U--P [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Z]+
-L-P [\\p{Punct}\\sa-z]+
--NP [\\p{Punct}\\s0-9]+
UL-P [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z]+
U-NP [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Z0-9]+
ULNP [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z0-9]+
```

What I have thus far (inefficient, with overlapping RegExs)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = new File("/home/tyler/workspace/PasswordAnalyzer/docs/test.txt");

try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        /*****************************************
        * Evaluate password Strings using RegExs
        ******************************************/
        if(s.matches("[A-Z0-9]+")){
            //Upper-case & numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[a-z0-9]+")){
            //Lower-case & numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")){
            //Alphanumeric

        } else if(s.matches("[A-Za-z]+")){
            //Upper-case & lower-case

        } else if(s.matches("[0-9]+")){
            //Numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[A-Z]+")){
            //Upper-case

        }  else if(s.matches("[a-z]+")){
            //Lower-case

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")){
            //Punctuation

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sA-Z]+")){
            //Punctuation & upper-case

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sa-z]+")){
            //Punctuation & lower-case

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\s0-9]+")){
            //Punctuation & numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z]+")){
            //Punctuation & alphabetical

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sA-Z0-9]+")){  
            //Punctuation & upper-case & numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sa-z0-9]+")){
            //Punctuation & lower-case & numeric

        } else if(s.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z0-9]+")){
            //Punctuation & alphanumeric

        } else {
            System.err.println("ERROR: unhandled RegEx");
        } 
    } //loop
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
    System.err.println(fnfe.getMessage());
}

}//main()
```

Revision:
Setting flags for 4 possible conditions (upper-case, lower-case, numeric, punctuation), dynamically generating the name of the corresponding variable, incrementing accordingly. Thoughts?

(bottom of main())

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = new File("/home/tyler/workspace/PasswordAnalyzer/docs/test.txt");
Analyzer a = new Analyzer(); //used by Java reflections object

try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        //Flags
        boolean U_flag = false;
        boolean L_flag = false;
        boolean N_flag = false;
        boolean P_flag = false;

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            String c = s.substring(i, i);
            /*****************************************
             * Set flags (U,L,N,P)
             ****************************************/
            //U_flag (upper-case)
            if(c.matches("[A-Z]+")){
                U_flag = true;
            }
            //L_flag (lower-case)
            if(c.matches("[a-z]+")){
                L_flag = true;
            }
            //N_flag (numeric)
            if(c.matches("[0-9]+")){
                N_flag = true;
            }
            //P_flag (punctuation)
            if(c.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")){
                P_flag = true;
            }
            /*****************************************
             * Identify corresponding counter variable
             ****************************************/
            String dest = "";

            //U_flag
            if(U_flag){dest.concat("U");
            } else {dest.concat("_");}

            //L_flag
            if(L_flag){dest.concat("L");
            } else {dest.concat("_");}

            //N_flag
            if(N_flag){dest.concat("N");
            } else {dest.concat("_");}

            //P_flag
            if(P_flag){dest.concat("P");}

            //increment variable stored in dest (Java reflections?)

        }//for-loop
    } //while-loop
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
    System.err.println(fnfe.getMessage());
}

}//main()
```

Comment: I assume you think that scanning a string multiple times is too slow?

Comment: Considered using `or` in the regular expression and then list all the regexps'es in a single regexp with or in between?

Comment: @durron597: I was considering tokenizing each row in the file, then having flags for each condition (so, if 'x' contains [A-Z]+ set UPPERCASE flag)

Comment: I mean that or something like it is the easiest solution, though I'm not sure it's the fastest. What's more valuable to you, programmer time or runtime?

Comment: Runtime is not an issue. I have laundry to do. It can be hideous, it just needs to serve a one-time utilitarian purpose, with a minimum of 95% accuracy.

Comment: It's not clear what your program isn't doing now that you are requesting we help you do.

Comment: @cheeken: What isn't clear? It reads each line of an external file and compares it to a given RegEx to determine which conditions the given String satisfies.

Comment: What it _does_ is clear.  But you're asking a question because you want it to do something it _doesn't_ do - and what that is what is unclear.

Comment: @cheeken: I'm asking how I can efficiently implement what it *doesn't*  do, as is the nature of Q&A AFAIK.

Comment: I think we're miscommunicating.  What you've posted looks like a working solution, but you asked this question to get help adding a feature.  What is that feature?

Comment: @cheeken: Yes, we absolutely are. Apologies mate, anyway I want to revise the horrid, nested if statement so that multiple conditions cannot be possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19690/discussion-between-tyler-j-fisher-and-cheeken)

Comment: The best solution is to NOT use regexes at all.  (Why do so many people automatically assume that regexes are the solution to any string parsing / matching problem??)

Comment: Thanks @wvxvw, I'll look into it next time. It looks like a wonderful project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, you have lots of overlap. For instance,

```
U--- [A-Z]+
UL-- [A-Za-z]+
U-N- [A-Z0-9]+
ULN- [A-Za-z0-9]+
ULNP [\\p{Punct}\\sA-Za-z0-9]+
```

Any string that is matched by the first regex will also be matched by any subsequent expression.

If I've interpreted your question correctly, you're trying to characterize each input string by which different character classes it contains.  For example, the string `ABCDE` is described as `U---`, while `Ab9b8` is `ULN-`.

To do this, all you have to do is (pseudocode):

```
for (String s in allStrings)
{
    int charClass = 0
    for (Char c in s.characters)
    {
        case c
            when upper-case: 
                charClas |= 8
                break;
            when lower-case: 
                charClas |= 4
                break;
            when numeric: 
                charClas |= 2
                break;                
            when punctuation: 
                charClas |= 1
                break;
    }
    // do something with charClass
}
```

At the "do something" comment, the value of `charClass`, taken as a bit string, will contain your `ULNP` value.  To convert that to a literal string containing `U`, `L`, `N` and `P`, you would set up a string array

```
String[] ulnpStrings = { "----","---P","--N-","--NP","-L--", "-L-P",... etc };
```

and then use the value of `charClass` as the index of that array.  To count the occurrences, do the same with an array

```
int[] ulnpCounts = new int[16];
```

and increment elements based on the value of charClass at each iteration, thus

```
    ...
    // do something with charClass
    unlpCounts[charClass]++
}
for (int i=0; i<unlpStrings.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%s %6d\n",unlpStrings[i],unlpCounts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Revised original question, attempting to use Java reflections to access variable, increment by 1 (since there are 14 possible fields to increment)

Comment: See my update. No need to use reflection, just use an array instead.

Comment: +1 - And to summarize the answer - it is simpler (and more efficient) to NOT use regexes to classify strings based on character classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:([A-Z]+)|([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)|([\\p{Punct}\\s]+)|.)*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLine())
{
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (m.reset(line).matches())
  {
    sb.append(m.start(1) > -1 ? "U" : "-");
    sb.append(m.start(2) > -1 ? "L" : "-");
    sb.append(m.start(3) > -1 ? "N" : "-");
    sb.append(m.start(4) > -1 ? "P" : "-");
  }
  System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", sb.toString(), line);
}
```

sample output:

```
U--- : AAAA
-L-- : aaaa
--N- : 2222
---P : %%%%
UL-- : AAAa
U-N- : AAA2
U--P : AAA%
```

Each type of character is assigned its own capturing group.  The `start(int)` method tells where the latest capture of that group started; a value of `-1` means that group didn't participate in the match.  (You could also use `m.group(int) != null`.)

I didn't do anything about failed matches because I don't know how you want to handle that.  Also, be aware that the dot in the last branch matches anything the other branches didn't, including non-ASCII letters, numbers, etc..   If you want to support other character sets, you'll have to use Unicode categories like `\p{Lu}`, `\p{Ll}`, etc..